# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

My code:

```
import sqlite3, os, urllib.request
from xml.dom import minidom

if os.path.exists("data.db"):
  con = sqlite3.connect("data.db")
  cursor = con.cursor()
  sql = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE test= '123'"
  cursor.execute(sql)
else:
  print("ERROR")

for dsatz in cursor:
  #print(dsatz)
  link = 'http://test.org/publication/' + dsatz[0] + '' + dsatz[1] +'/bib'
  #print(link)

  web_data = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
  xmldoc = minidom.parse(web_data)

  di = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("document-id")[:1]

  for x in di:
      publicationcountry = x.getElementsByTagName("country")[0].firstChild.data
      publicationdocnumber = x.getElementsByTagName("doc-number")[0].firstChild.data
      punlicationkind = x.getElementsByTagName("kind")[0].firstChild.data
      publicationdate = x.getElementsByTagName("date")[0].firstChild.data     

      sql = "INSERT INTO link_xml_data VALUES('" \
      + publicationcountry + "', '" \
      + str(publicationdocnumber) + "', '" \
      + punlicationkind + "')"

      con.close()
```

But after like 15 links I get the ERROR :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\j\3.py", line 34, in <module>
    web_data = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
  File "C:\Users\j\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\j\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 472, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\j\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 582, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\j\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 510, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\j\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\j\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 590, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

What do should I add or change?

Answer (score 0):

The web server is telling you that link is forbidden.  There's (probably) nothing wrong with your code.

Do some links always work and other links always fail, or does the pattern change over time?

After getting a 403 Forbidden response, have you tried going back and re-requesting one of the earlier successful links?

Perhaps the server eventually recognizes you as a web scraper and is telling you to go away?